Getting coefficients list of a series expansion at a point different from 0
I would like to get the coefficients of a series expansion at a point different from 0. Example:
Series[Cos[Pi*x], {x,1,6}] 

which gives
$-1+\frac{1}{2} \pi ^2 (x-1)^2-\frac{1}{24} \pi ^4 (x-1)^4+\frac{1}{720} \pi ^6 (x-1)^6+O\left((x-1)^7\right)$
Now, if I try to get the coefficients as a list, I do:
CoefficientList[Series[Cos[Pi*x], {x, 1, 6}], x]

which gives
$
\left\{-1+\frac{\pi ^2}{2}-\frac{\pi ^4}{24}+\frac{\pi ^6}{720},-\pi ^2+\frac{\pi ^4}{6}-\frac{\pi ^6}{120},\frac{\pi ^2}{2}-\frac{\pi ^4}{4}+\frac{\pi ^6}{48},\frac{\pi ^4}{6}-\frac{\pi ^6}{36},\frac{\pi ^6}{48}-\frac{\pi ^4}{24},-\frac{\pi ^6}{120},\frac{\pi ^6}{720}\right\}$
although I would expect to get
$\left\{-1, \frac{1}{2} \pi ^2 , -\frac{1}{24} \pi ^4 , \frac{1}{720} \pi ^6 \right\}$
I suspect that the error comes from the fact that I use the variable x in the call to CoefficientList instead of x-1 but using directly x-1 doesn't work.
How to get correctly the coefficients of the x-1 powers ?

`In[1316]:= Series[Cos[Pi*x], {x, 1, 6}][[3]]
Out[1316]= {-1, 0, [Pi]^2/2, 0, -([Pi]^4/24), 0, [Pi]^6/720}`

One way is to do the following: expand to whatever order you want, and subsequently substitute $x-1$ by $y$. Do CoefficientList in the y. This is implemented in the following way:
Series[Cos[π x], {x, 1, 6}] // Normal
% /. (x - 1)^a_. :> y^a
CoefficientList[%, y]


{-1, 0, π^2/2, 0, -(π^4/24), 0, π^6/720}

